# New Computer, will not power up

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, power

I bought parts to build a new PC and there is a problem.
I tested the power supply via the paper clip test and it works just fine. When I plug the PSU into the Motherboard however, no fans spin, not even the one on the PSU.

When looking on the internet for advice, I tried putting a paper clip through the motherboard power header to connect the green and black pins manually and force the motherboard to be powered on.
At this point, video card fans turned on, the PSU fan turned on and the case power light turned on.
However, nothing else worked, and the video card fans would often stutter.

Does anybody have any advice? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you sure the power button on the case is properly connected onto the motherboard?

Comment: This might be silly, but I missed a heart beat when I ran into the same issue, are you sure the power button on the PSU is on? They ship with off state ...

Comment: Yes, I am sure the power button is properly connected to the Motherboard, but the problems still persist

Comment: This is a good selection of common probs - http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/261145-31-perform-steps-posting-post-boot-video-problems

Comment: Alas, I have already consulted that list and none of the solutions suggested were able to fix my problem

Comment: Try eliminating components, unplug any sata devices and remove the video card and try again. Ensure your cpu and ram are properly seated - double check you haven't installed an extra riser that you can't see (count them on the back)

Comment: Did you already put the motherboard in your case?
I once had 1 standoff too much in my case, which caused a short and showed the same issues you are having.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out what needed to be done was to [clear the CMOS settings](http://www.howtogeek.com/131623/how-to-clear-your-computers-cmos-to-reset-bios-settings/).
I used the jumper to clear it and it started working right away.
Thanks to everybody who tried to help.

Answer (score 0):

As you were able to get the power to apply when playing with the motherboard header for the power switch I would check that you have the power switch pins the right way around and temporarily disconnect the reset switch while doing so.

Early on when I was building computers I got the power switch the wrong way around and had this exact problem.